# Socket io connection disconnect after some time

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, firefox, browser, socket.io

I notice after few hours browser disconnect from scoket server, I belive it is something issue with browser maybe it close connection after some time without activity...

I connected something like this:

```
this.socket = io(environment.socketUrl, {
                reconnection: true,
                reconnectionDelay: 1000,
                reconnectionDelayMax: 5000,
                reconnectionAttempts: Infinity,
                forceNew: true,
                secure: true,
                query: "token=" + this.authService.getToken()
            });
```

and it force connection after disconnect but it is not good because I need stabile connection without braking. Is there some way to prevent browser disconnection?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to guarantee a constant connection. It is best to plan for a reconnect on both client and server side.

Comment: How can I try reconnect from server side?

Comment: Only the client can reconnect. It should reconnect automatically by default. Read the docs here https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#new-Manager-url-options